# How pass data in seque ios5 storyboard uitableview to detail view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I'm creating an app in ios5 using storyboards. I have a tableviewcontroller embedded in a navigation controller and when you click on the cells in the tableviewcontroller some detail about that cell topic should be passed to a detail view. I use a plist to populate the tableview and the detail view. I've done this fine without using storyboard but want to learn how to use storyboard. I have seque going to my detail view from the tableviewcontroller.

My code for the seque is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewControllerSeque"])
    {   DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];  
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questList.plist"];
        NSArray *tempArray = [finalPath valueForKey:@"description"];
        NSString *descriptionString = [tempArray valueForKey:@"description"];
        detailViewController.detailDescriptionText.text = descriptionString;    
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 66):

I was having the same problem (from lack of experience with iOS5).

It turns out that is an example app with the iOS5 SDK which has a table view that uses segues when a table cell is tapped : "Simple Drill Down".

https://web.archive.org/web/20130513140140/http://developer.apple.com:80/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

You do set the segue at the table cell and give it a name in the storyboard file.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    /*
     When a row is selected, the segue creates the detail view controller as the destination.
     Set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
     */
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSelectedPlay"]) {

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.play = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks many times over. Been stuck with this for several hours. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `dataController` coming from?

Comment: If understand the question, the data is handled in the segue method: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Answer (score 12):

I got the same problem, Followed parts of Ray Wenderlich tutorial and found that you need to select table cell and Ctrl-Drag to your viewcontroller. Then call  `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtINdexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueId" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   
        NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier  );      
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegueId"])
        {
            DetailController *detailController = segue.destinationViewController;
            detailController.delegate = (id)self;
            detailController.selected = selectedRow;
        }   
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I wanted!  There is an error here detailControllerController, won't let me edit or I'd fix it myself.

Comment: both answers helped me, but I was surprised that I also needed this one. I thought Apple would have implemented like that that it would be enough to connect the cells with the next scene without having to tell which segue to perform....
anyway, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need Call: 
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueId" sender:self];`

you could use `NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` to get your selected info, in your `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{...}` function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and haven't solved it yet with storyboards. However, I think that the segue should start at the cell, not the entire tableviewcontroller. if you use prototype cells, this could work - but i don't know about code-created cell types. would appreciate any help on this topic, too.

Edit:
The tutorial at http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html suggests that no segue solution exists and you still have to do the transition to detail view in code. I don't know how correct this is, but I will just do it that way until someone shows me the pure storyboarding/segue solution ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

First Name Your segue(from tableview cell to detail view).Then

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueName"]){

        DetailViewController * detailViewController =segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController =[self.yourTableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:[self.yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];

    }

}
```

Don't forget to import your SecondViewController/DetailViewController