# How to send a value to a ViewController when a button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have two buttons in my `SearchCategoryChooserViewController`. What I want to do is to set the `chosenCategory` property to a certain value depending on which button is pressed, and then send that value over to `CriteriaViewController`.

I have some psuedo code commented out in my `categoryButtonClick` function, but I'm not sure how to format the syntax, and where to take it from there. The `topCategoryId1` and `topCategoryId2` values are coming from `SearchViewController`. Let me know if you want me to include code from that or any other classes.

**SearchCategoryChooserViewController.m**:

```
#import "SearchCategoryChooserViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "CriteriaViewController.h"

@interface SearchCategoryChooserViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchCategoryChooserViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    UIButton *category1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    category1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 120, 300, 35);
    [category1 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.topCategory1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [category1 addTarget:self action:@selector(categoryButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview: category1];


    UIButton *category2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    category2.frame = CGRectMake(10, 180, 300, 35);
    [category2 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.topCategory2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [category2 addTarget:self action:@selector(categoryButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview: category2];


}




- (IBAction)categoryButtonClick:(id)sender
{
//    if (topCategory1 button is pressed) {
//        set chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1
//    }
//    
//    else if (topCategory2 button is pressed) {
//        set chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId2
//    }

}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// Send the Category Id over to CriteriaViewController
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

 CriteriaViewController *controller = (CriteriaViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;

 // Send over the search query as well as the specific category to CriteriaVC to use
 controller.chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1;



}


@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios pass values during a segue to another view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907684/ios-pass-values-during-a-segue-to-another-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use tags. Set each button to have its own tag after creating it, for example:

```
UIButton *category1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
category1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 120, 300, 35);
[category1 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.topCategory1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[category1 addTarget:self action:@selector(categoryButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
category1.tag = 1;  //added tag to button
[self.view addSubview: category1];


UIButton *category2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
category2.frame = CGRectMake(10, 180, 300, 35);
[category2 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.topCategory2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[category2 addTarget:self action:@selector(categoryButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
category2.tag = 2;  //added tag to button
[self.view addSubview: category2];
```

Then in your button action method (categoryButtonClick:), check the button's tag like so:

```
- (IBAction)categoryButtonClick:(id)sender
{ UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
  if(button.tag == 1){
        chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1;
   }else{
        chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId2;
   }

}
```

Comment: This all makes sense, however this line: `chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1;
    }else{
        chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId2;`

is giving me the error `use of undeclared identifier chosenCategory`. Where should I be declaring it?

Comment: I was simply going off of your psuedo code. What is `chosenCategory` supposed to be?

Comment: You have said that `chosenCategory` is a property. It isn't?

Comment: Yes `chosenCategory` is an NSNumber property that I'll be sending over to `CriteriaViewController`.

Comment: Inserting this: `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *chosenCategory;` into the header file of the `SearchViewController` that `SearchCategoryChooserViewController` imports from doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Try this: In your header file of your SearchCategoryChooserViewController, add a property called chosenCategory and set that value in your button's action method (`self.chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1` or `self.chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId2` respectively). Then when you prepareForSegue, set `controller.chosenCategory = self.chosenCategory`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
- (IBAction)categoryButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    if ([topCategory1 isSelected]) {
        set chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1
    }

    else if ([topCategory2 isSelected]) {
        set chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In adition to the @croberth's answer, after conditionally setting `chosenCategory`, send a `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` message:

```
- (IBAction)categoryButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(button.tag == 1) {
        chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId1;
    }
    else {
        chosenCategory = self.topCategoryId2;
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" sender:nil];
}
```

`YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER` is the identifier for your segue between the button and the `CriteriaViewController`. Since your buttons aren't in your storyboard, it should be a segue between the 2 controllers, not from any button.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking has been answered several times already on SO.  You set up a variable in the sending VC in the prepareForSegue method and prepare a variable to receive that value in the receiving VC. Here's an SO link with a lot more detail: [ios pass values during a segue to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907684/ios-pass-values-during-a-segue-to-another-view)