# Passing NSMutableArray to other class returns empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I've read other answers about this and at first I had a (null) error, but that is now fixed. Now, whenever I log my NSMutableArray, which I created in "SelectTeacherTableViewController.h" and passed to the SendMessageViewController class, it creates an array, but it is empty.

Here is the code from my SelectTeacherTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SelectTeacherTableViewController :
UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *recipients;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *teachers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *recipients;

@end
```

Here is the code from my SelectTeacherTableViewController, where I synthesize the recipients and add objects to them through a method. (Code shortened)

```
#import "ParseStarterProjectAppDelegate.h"
#import "SelectTeacherTableViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface SelectTeacherTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SelectTeacherTableViewController
@synthesize recipients;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Message";
    self.recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [PFUser logInWithUsername:@"awesome" password:@"password"];
    NSString *getCurrentUserSchoolKey = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"schoolKey"];
    NSString *currentUserSchoolKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getCurrentUserSchoolKey];
    PFQuery *queryForTeachers = [PFUser query];
    [queryForTeachers orderByAscending: @"username"];
    [queryForTeachers whereKey: @"role" equalTo:@"Teacher"];
    [queryForTeachers whereKey:@"schoolKey" equalTo:currentUserSchoolKey];
    [queryForTeachers findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {
        self.teachers = objects;
        NSLog(currentUserSchoolKey);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFUser *user = [self.teachers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [recipients addObject:user.objectId];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [recipients removeObject:user.objectId];
}

NSLog(@"%@", recipients);
}
```

When I log the recipients here, they do contain all of the correct values. However, this is my SendMessageViewController where I pass the array from the SelectTeacherTableViewController:

SendMessageViewController.m (Code Shortened):

```
#import "SendMessageViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import "SelectTeacherTableViewController.h"

@interface SendMessageViewController ()
@end

@implementation SendMessageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SelectTeacherTableViewController *recipientList = [[SelectTeacherTableViewController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:recipientList.recipients];
    NSLog(@"%@", recipientList);
}
```

It's here where when I log the recipients, the array is empty.

I've read about it a little and encountered some solutions which said some things about creating simpleton files, or using the AppDelegate to store global variables in, but none of those solutions seemed to work for me. I have a feeling that the data is being lost when I segue. Is there anywhere where I have gone wrong in my code? I'm a little new to Objective-C and this problem has been bugging me for hours. Thanks.

If you need to see any more code, just ask me. Thanks.

Comment: both answer below are correct, you just create a new instance of your controller. please have look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907684/ios-pass-values-during-a-segue-to-another-view there are some answers to your question.

Comment: So should I pass the data through a segue using prepareForSegue?

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much! Finally did it!

Comment: You don't pass the data in, you pass a _reference_ to the data. There's a subtle difference that I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `SelectTeacherTableViewController *recipientList = [[SelectTeacherTableViewController alloc] init];` creates a new object.  Anything you added to a `recipients` array inside some other `SelectTeacherTableViewController` is irrelevant.

If you need to use the information that you've added to the original object, you must pass a reference to that object…not create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`[[SelectTeacherTableViewController alloc] init]` does NOT give you a reference to your existing recipient list, it creates a NEW ONE. In object oriented programming you can have multiple instances of the same class that are NOT the same object.

**Class != Object**