# Accessing variable from different View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, variables, storyboard

I have developed an application using a `TableView` connected to a SQLite database with a search bar and everything works well.
I have a detail view controller that shows me infos about a clicked row. How can I pass a variable from `AuthorVC.m` to `Details.m`?

Partial code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);  
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"]) 
        // segue.identifier value here   
    {      
        Details *dv = segue.destinationViewController;
        dv.labelText.text = author.title;
        //  author.title = dv.labelText.text ;
        // your value to pass     

        [segue.destinationViewController setLabelText:author.title];     
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Create property of variable in myDetails to pass data
Suppose i have NSString *strAuthoTitle in myDetails

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
 //Depending upon cell index pass your data differently
 myDetails *objmyDetails = [myDetails alloc] initWithNib:@"myDetails" bundle:nil] //alloc your controller for navigation 

 objmyDetails.strAuthoTitle = [yourArrayofAuthorTile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 //Simarly other data can be passed
}
```

As u not mentioned that u were using storyboard so for that u need to create a segue between AuthorVC to Details controlers and use that segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {   
  //NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);      
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailsPass"]) // segue.identifier value here
  {
   objmyDetails = segue.destinationViewController;
   objmyDetails.strText =lblText.text; // your value to pass
   //[segue.destinationViewController setStrText:lblText.text];
  }   
 }
```

Comment: I am using Storyboard so i have no xib files .. is there any equivalent method

Comment: I tried putting it in the AuthorVC.m , but i am sure that it's not read by the debugger. I removed the " // " from the slog tag and there is nthg shown....any ideas?

Comment: Check the edited question to see my implementation whether i am on the right track please

Answer (score 0):

With story board

[How pass data in seque ios5 storyboard uitableview to detail view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937035/how-pass-data-in-seque-ios5-storyboard-uitableview-to-detail-view)

http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html

---

Without story board
For this you have to access varible in class one let see below example for example on click of table row you have to navigate on another view say root view. So for this define a variable in root view and access this view when you create object in didselect method of table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

//Increment the Current View
rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;

//Set the title;
rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

//Push the new table view on the stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

[rv release]
}
```

Comment: The thing is i am using IOS 5 with storyboards...i cannot use initWithNibName...i have no xib files

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have 2  properties in your detailedVC `strName` and `strDescription`...

than before pushing the detailedVC in the stack, you could simple do something like:

```
detailedVCObject.strName = @"whatever";
detailedVCObject.strDescription = @"whatever";
```

hope it would help...

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more i am new to storyboards :s