# displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar randomly triggers searchBar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

So I was trying to combine the search bar with the Nav bar for tableview in iOS7.

I called
`self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;` And it looks fine.

However, when I tap anywhere in the tableview, the search bar is activated. There's essentially no way I can regularly click a table cell.

I'm wondering what exactly did I miss here?

And for reference the code related to tableview looks like this: (I used storyboard to handle click logic)

```
    #pragma mark - Table view delegate method

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] count];;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [self.contacts[section] count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"contactCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    Contact *contact;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        contact = searchResults[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        contact = [[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
    UIImageView *starMark = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:9];

    NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.firstName, contact.lastName];

    if ([contact.star isEqual:@0]) {
        starMark.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        starMark.hidden = NO;
    }

    [nameLabel setText:nameString];

    return cell;
}
```

And the segue method is defined here:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushContactDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath;
        Contact *contact;
        if (self.searchDisplayController.active == YES) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            contact = searchResults[indexPath.row];
        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            contact = [[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        //get indexPath from selected sushi

        //initialize the detail view controller and push it
        CIContactViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your tableview?

Comment: You say that you used a storyboard to handle the click logic. It may be that you need to implement the - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender method. See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7937035/35499) which talks about this.

Comment: Oh, I do have that method. Just give me one sec to post it

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your prepareForSegue method and then select one of the rows in your table view, does it go there and is the if statement (if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushContactDetail"])) true?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Just by removing the tab bar out of the tableview element in Storyboard works fine!