# Passing data from Table View Controller to Embedded Container View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

The data from the cell in **Job Table View Controller** needs to be pased to **Job Detail View Controller**.

Passing data from **Job Table View Controller** to **Job Container View Controller** is not a problem using PrepareForSegue.
[image]

1. I've tried sending a NSNotification from **Job Table View Controller** but the **Job Detail View Controller**'s viewDidLoad is loaded before the NSNotification get's triggered and I don't think this is good programming.
2. I've tried delegate but the **Job Table View Controller** does not have a reference to the **Job Detail View Controller**.
3. I've tried making an outlet connection of the **Container view** in **Job Container View Controller** but it's of type UIView so I cannot find a reference to **Job Detail View Controller** in it?

What is the proper way to do this? Many thanks guys!

**JobTableViewController.m** this works.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Job * selectedJob = [listOfJobs objectAtIndex:path.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] sendSelectedJob:selectedJob];
}
```

**JobContainerViewController.m**

```
Job * currentJob;
@synthesize jobDescriptionLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self updateFields:currentJob];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [[segue destinationViewController] sendSelectedJob:currentJob];
}

-(void) updateFields:(Job *)job {
    jobDescriptionLabel.text = job.job_name;
}

- (void) sendSelectedJob:(Job *)currentjob {
    currentJob = currentjob;
}
```

**JobDetailViewController.m**

```
Job *job;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self updateFields:job];
}

- (void) sendSelectedJob:(Job *)currentjob {
    job = currentjob;
}

-(void)updateFields:(Job *) job {
   // update fields 
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8658082/361247

Comment: no @EnricoSusatyo i'm asking for the detail view controller to the right. PrepareForSegue works as written in my post.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?? I still haven't solved this problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the same way to pass the data to the detail VC. How are you pushing the JobDetailViewController?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo I've added prepareForSegue in JobContainerView which works indeed. It made more sense to me that you should not pass data through views. Instead have one view that sends this to all "listeners". Furthermore **showDataOnJobDetails** can only set a class variable, currentjob and in viewDidLoad I can call updateFields. I'm afraid it could be possible that the job object could be potentially nil.

Comment: Jim, you're not answering my question. What I'm wondering is how do you push the JobDetailViewController? You should set the data at that point just after you pushed. It's not a bad practice to send data through view controllers btw.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo prepareForSegue in ** JobContainerViewController** gets fired right after viewDidLoad. So that works :).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't grasp the entire situation yet. I think the below is what you need. First of all, you will need to have a share model that contains the all the job data.

Under **Job Detail View Controller**:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showDataOnJobDetails) name:@"showDataOnJobDetails" object:nil];
 }

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"showDataOnJobDetails" object:nil];
}

-(void)showDataOnJobDetails{
  //TODO: Update whatever you need on showDataOnJobDetails using data from Share Model.
}
```

Under the **viewDidAppear** for **Job Container View Controller**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showDataOnJobDetails" object:nil];
```

Comment: After carefully analyzing your question I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't work. viewWillAppear is too late, the NSNotification has already been sent, but no listeners at that point in time!